# Method to count the number of books of an author

Tags: java, arrays

So I need to create 3 classes "Book"(with fields author, title and body, as string), "Shelf"(with fields id (string) and books (array) and "Library". Then I shall create a method "countAuthor".which counts (and returns as an int) the number of books in the library written by an author whose name (String) is passed as an argument to the method:

```
    class Book {
    private String author;
    public String getAuthor() {return author;}
    private String title;
    public String getTitle() {return title;}
    private String body;
    public String getBody() {return body;}
}

class Shelf {
    private String id;
    public String getId() {return id;}
    private int[] books;
    public int[] getBooks() {return books;}

}

class Library {
    private int[] shelves;
    public int[] getShelves() {return shelves;}
    public int countAuthor(String authorName) { // returns the number of books in the library written by author whose name (String)
                                      //is passed as an argument to the method.
        int a = ;
        return a; // a is the number of books of the author
    }
}
```

After all, in the class (where the main method is stated), I need to add the necessary code and the program overall shall print the number of books an author has written. This is the class of the main method:

```
    public class Exercise {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Shelf shelf1 = new Shelf("Shelf1",
                    new Book[] {
                            new Book("Babel", "Odessa Tales", "babelode"),
                            new Book("Joyce", "Ulisses", "joyceuli")
                            });
            Shelf shelf2 = new Shelf("Shelf2",
                    new Book[] {
                            new Book("Mann", "Dr Faustus", "mannfau"),
                            new Book("Babel", "Red Cavalry", "babelred")
                            });
            Library lib = new Library(
                    new Shelf[] { shelf1, shelf2 });
            System.out.println("# of books by this author: " + lib.countAuthor("Babel"));
        }
    }
```

Which should print `# of book by this author: 2`

Where I am confused with is what to add to the `countAuthor()` method. And if I need anything in addition to the method. I am pretty new to Java so I still get confused with some structures, especially with the loops.

Comment: What would a pseudocode solution look like?

Comment: Please fix compilation errors first. Your syntax of creating arrays and objects is incorrect. You are missing constructors that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. In your code you are missing constructors that you are trying to use so I added them. The logic of counting the books is just go through all the shelves in the lib and count all the books on these shelves with the author name.

```
public class Exercise {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shelf shelf1 = new Shelf("Shelf1", new Book[]{
        new Book("Babel", "Odessa Tales", "babelode"),
        new Book("Joyce", "Ulisses", "joyceuli")});
    Shelf shelf2 = new Shelf("Shelf2",
        new Book[]{
            new Book("Mann", "Dr Faustus", "mannfau"),
            new Book("Babel", "Red Cavalry", "babelred")
        });
    Library lib = new Library(new Shelf[]{shelf1, shelf2});
    System.out.println("# of books by this author: " + lib.countAuthor("Babel"));
  }
}

class Book {

  public Book(String author, String title, String body) {
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
  }

  private String author;

  public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }

  private String title;

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  private String body;

  public String getBody() {
    return body;
  }
}

class Shelf {

  public Shelf(String id, Book[] books) {
    this.id = id;
    this.books = books;
  }

  private String id;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  private Book[] books;

  public Book[] getBooks() {
    return books;
  }

}

class Library {

  public Library(Shelf[] shelves) {
    this.shelves = shelves;
  }

  private Shelf[] shelves;

  public Shelf[] getShelves() {
    return shelves;
  }

  public int countAuthor(
      String authorName) { // returns the number of books in the library written by author whose name (String)
    //is passed as an argument to the method.
    int count = 0;
    for (Shelf shelf : shelves) {
      for (Book book : shelf.getBooks()) {
        if (book.getAuthor().equals(authorName)) {
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
    return count; // a is the number of books of the author
  }
}
```

Output:

```
# of books by this author: 2
```

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. I did a search about constructors but I could not understand the concept clearly. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your question, the structure will be like this.

**Library can have many Shelf and in every Shelf there are many books.**

So to count the no of books for a particular author, first you need all the books.

It will be something like this.

```
public int countAuthor(String author) {
   int result = 0;
   for(Shelf shelf : shelves) {
      for(Book book : shelf.getBooks()) {
          if(author.equals(book.getAuthor()) {
             result++;
          }
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```